# javascript - grab title, price and color of product from webpage

Tags: javascript

**What I want:** From the below URL, I would like to grab: `Title`, `Was Price`, `Now Price`, `all colors aviable`

https://www.michaelkors.com/mercer-gallery-medium-logo-tote-bag/_/R-US_30F1GZ5T6B?color=2170

- Title = Mercer Gallery Medium Logo Tote Bag
- Was Price = $398.00
- Now Price = $149.00
- Color = BRN/SFTPINK, BRN/ACORN

After inspecting URL code, I need to grab data from the following classes `product-name`, `listPrice` and `salePrice`

> Error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.michaelkors.com/greenwich-extra-small-studded-patent-leather-crossbody-bag/_/R-US_32F1GGRC5L?color=2711' from origin 'https://localhost:44329' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**What I Tried:**

```js
var url = 'https://www.michaelkors.com/mercer-gallery-medium-logo-tote-bag/_/R-US_30F1GZ5T6B?color=2170';

        var TitleClass = 'product-name';



        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(text => {
                document.getElementById('DisplayWebCode').innerHTML = text;
                console.log(text);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

```html
<div id="DisplayWebCode">

    </div>
```

Comment: Read about CORS policy. Basically it is not allowed to access another domain (that you do not own) with JS. What you can do is to run headless browser, for example with Node.js, and parse any page you like.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is possible. Just not on browser javascript. **You'll need NodeJS.** 
You can use web **scraping** technologies to render out web pages and extract the title, price etc. in the **backend** and serve that in an API and then make a fetch request to that from your frontend. You can use Puppeteer to do the scraping bit. Please check out [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) for more info.